# Is it possible to set a dynamic variable name?

Tags: variables, batch-file, dynamic

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
set wordNum=1
set word=Test
:: ^
::This stuff is just so that if people want to
::test it, they have all the variables they need.

set word%wordnum%=%word%
set file=!word%wordNum%!
echo %file%
```

If so, what am I doing wrong?
In context, I'm trying to remind the computer of the last word it recorded.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost done.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set wordNum=1
set word=Test

set word%wordnum%=%word%
set file=!word%wordNum%!

echo %file%
```

To use delayed expansion you need to enable it

Comment: I forgot to mention, it is already enabled at the beginning of the program.

Comment: @Aty'ai, well, in that case the code you posted works without problems.

Comment: I found my issue, I had a goto randomly inserted into the middle of all of that so it never set the !word%wordNum%!. Thank you for your help.